# help with determining space curves (slanted ellipses) of semi-major axes of ellipsoid

Tags: conic-sections

I have an ellipsoid centered at the origin whose equation is:
$$10.5x^2+10.5y^2+1z^2+2(9.5)xy+2(0)xz+2(0)yz=1$$

How can the space curves (slanted ellipses) of this ellipsoid's semi-major axes be determined? The curves are defined in terms of $t$:

$$x(t)=f(t), y(t)=f(t),z(t)=f(t)$$

where $f(t)$ is some trigonometric function such as $\sin$ or $\cos$, and $t$ ranges from 0 to 2$\pi$

And what to do for even more complicated ellipsoids, e.g., if the $xz$ and $yz$ terms are non-zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a *quadric* of Cartesian equation:

$$
\small
a_{11}\,x^2+a_{22}\,y^2+a_{33}\,z^2+2\,a_{12}\,x\,y + 2\,a_{13}\,x\,z + 2\,a_{23}\,y\,z + 2\,a_{14}\,x + 2\,a_{24}\,y + 2\,a_{34}\,z + a_{44} = 0
$$

the first thing is to build the respective *real and symmetric matrices*:

$$
A_1 \equiv
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
a_{12} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
a_{13} & a_{23} & a_{33} & a_{34} \\
a_{14} & a_{24} & a_{34} & a_{44} \\
\end{bmatrix},
\quad \quad \quad
A_2 \equiv
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{12} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{13} & a_{23} & a_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

So, whenever:

$$
\det(A_1) \ne 0,
\quad \quad \quad
\det(A_2) \ne 0
$$

it's a *non-degenerate quadric* whose *center* is the solution of the *system of linear equations*:

$$
\begin{cases}
a_{11}\,x + a_{12}\,y + a_{13}\,z + a_{14} = 0 \\
a_{12}\,x + a_{22}\,y + a_{23}\,z + a_{24} = 0 \\
a_{13}\,x + a_{23}\,y + a_{33}\,z + a_{34} = 0 \\
\end{cases}
\quad \quad \Rightarrow \quad \quad
C=(x_c,y_c,z_c).
$$

In particular, if $\det(A_1)<0$ and the eigenvalues of $A_2$ have the same sign, it's a *real ellipsoid*.

So, if the eigenvalues of $A_2$ are $\lambda_1,\,\lambda_2,\,\lambda_3$ and the orthonormal eigenvectors are $\mathbf{u}_1,\,\mathbf{u}_2,\,\mathbf{u}_3$:

$$
\boxed{\mathcal{E}(u,v) = C + 
\frac{\mathbf{u}_1}{\sqrt{|\lambda_1|}}\,\cos u\,\cos v + 
\frac{\mathbf{u}_2}{\sqrt{|\lambda_2|}}\,\cos u\,\sin v +
\frac{\mathbf{u}_3}{\sqrt{|\lambda_3|}}\,\sin u\;}
$$

with $-\frac{\pi}{2} \le u \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0 \le v < 2\pi$ is a parametrization of the *real ellipsoid* considered.

Therefore, the *principal ellipses* are trivially obtained by setting:

$$
\boxed{\mathcal{E}_1(t) = \mathcal{E}\left(0,t\right),
\quad \quad \quad
\mathcal{E}_2(t) = \mathcal{E}\left(t,0\right),
\quad \quad \quad
\mathcal{E}_3(t) = \mathcal{E}\left(t,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\;}
$$

where, in all three parametrizations, we have $0 \le t < 2\pi$.

---

**ADDENDUM**:

Given the *quadric* of Cartesian equation:

$$
\left(15+4\sqrt{2}\right)x^2+\left(15-4\sqrt{2}\right)y^2+13\,z^2 + 4\,x\,y + \left(8+4\sqrt{2}\right)x\,z + \left(8-4\sqrt{2}\right)y\,z - 1 = 0
$$

it's easy to verify that it's a *real ellipsoid* with center $O$ and the eigen/values/vectors of $A_2$ are:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \lambda_1 = 25,
\quad \quad \;\; 
\mathbf{u}_1 = \left(\sqrt{2}+1,\,\sqrt{2}-1,\,\sqrt{2}\right); \\
& \lambda_2 = 9,
\quad \quad \quad 
\mathbf{u}_2 = \left(\sqrt{2}-2,\,0,\,1\right); \\
& \lambda_3 = 9,
\quad \quad \quad 
\mathbf{u}_3 = \left(2\sqrt{2}-3,\,1,\,0\right); \\
\end{aligned}
$$

but since $\lambda_2=\lambda_3$ not always $\mathbf{u}_2\perp\mathbf{u}_3$; in fact, it's $\mathbf{u}_2\cdot\mathbf{u}_3 = 10-7\sqrt{2}\ne 0$.

So, in these cases it's necessary to apply the *Gram–Schmidt process*, by which we obtain:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \mathbf{u}_1 = \left(\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{4},\,\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{4},\,\frac{1}{2}\right); \\
& \mathbf{u}_2 = \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}-2}{\sqrt{7-4\sqrt{2}}},\,0,\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{7-4\sqrt{2}}}\right); \\
& \mathbf{u}_3 = \left(\frac{2\sqrt{2}-3}{2\sqrt{74-52\sqrt{2}}},\,\frac{7-4\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{74-52\sqrt{2}}},\,\frac{7\sqrt{2}-10}{2\sqrt{74-52\sqrt{2}}}\right); \\
\end{aligned}
$$

which are eigenvectors of $A_2$ of *unit length* and *orthogonal to each other*, as desired.

In all those cases where the eigenvectors are already orthogonal, it's sufficient to normalize them!

Comment: (+1) are $\mathbf{u}_i$ normalized (unit) eigenvectors? And how to handle the computation of, e.g., $\mathbf{u}_1/\sqrt{|\lambda_1|}$ since $\mathbf{u}_1$ is a vector of three components (three numerical values)?

Comment: (+1) Just to be sure, in dividing each component of the unit vectors, the equation is more explicitly as follows? $\mathcal{E}(u,v) = C + \frac{\left(u_{1x}+u_{1y}+u_{1z}\right)}{\sqrt{|\lambda_1|}}\,\cos u\,\cos v + \frac{\left(u_{2x}+u_{2y}+u_{2z}\right)}{\sqrt{|\lambda_2|}}\,\cos u\,\sin v +\frac{\left(u_{3x}+u_{3y}+u_{3z}\right)}{\sqrt{|\lambda_3|}}\,\sin u$

Comment: Also, I'm still having trouble seeing what are the equations for the x, y, and z coordinates of the principal ellipses. E.g., for $\mathcal{E}_1(t) = \mathcal{E}\left(0,t\right)$ what are the equations for $\mathcal{E}_{1x}(t), \mathcal{E}_{1y}(t), \mathcal{E}_{1z}(t)$? (I hope this makes sense).

Comment: (+1) I've included an image of your ellipsoid with principal axes and ellipses using what you've taught me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

@TeM (+1) I've included an image of your ellipsoid with principal axes and ellipses using what you've taught me. Thanks!

[image]
[image]